# BV linear Gradient module not found in UI manager

Tags: reactjs, react-native

this error occurs when i try to install react-native-linear-gradient shows BV linear gradient UI not found in UI manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this issue in easy ways

uninstall react-native-linear gradient cd ios && pod install

after uninstalling completely go to xcode.workspace =>product=>clean build

run-ios
after successfully running

npm install react-native-linear-gradient then cd ios && pod install

you must see autolinking for react-native-linear gradient

uninstall the app and run-ios/run-android
It will work properly

Note = Don't do manually linking if your react native version > 0.60